# Changing object references in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

Here I generate a 4 x 8 panel with images and I save the reference into block.

```
local function createBlocks()

local rowcount = 8
    local colcount = 4

    local blockWidth = display.contentWidth / (colcount*4)
    local blockHeight = display.contentWidth / (rowcount*2)

    local row
    local col
    local pan = 3
    local i=0
    for row = 1, rowcount do
            for col = 1, colcount do
                    local x = (col - 1) * blockWidth + pan
                    local y = (row + 1) * blockHeight + pan
                    local random= math.random(1,6)

                    random = revisarTres(i, random)

                    print (random)
                    block[i] = display.newImage(images[random], x, y)
                    block[i].value= random     
                    block[i]:addEventListener("touch", blockTouch)
                    i=i+1
            end
    end
```

end

Then I add an event listener, to see if they have touched the image.
Then I validate that if they have made a touch, it  made the transition here.

```
transition.to(startBlock, {time=tranTime, x=event.target.x, y=event.target.y})
transition.to(event.target, {time=tranTime, x=startBlock.x, y=startBlock.y})
```

But I want to update this change in the block array. So I made this:

```
aux = block[old]
            auxval = block[old].value
            block[old]= block[new]
            block[old].value= block[new].value
            block[new]= block[old]
            block[new].value= auxval
```

but it isn`t working, I want to know a way to change the reference value.

I hope you can save me, please.

Answer (score 1):

I want to say your exchange two value‘s function is wrong, see:

```
aux = block[old]
auxval = block[old].value
block[old]= block[new]
block[old].value= block[new].value
block[new]= block[old]
block[new].value= auxval
```

that's ugly,if you want to exchange block[old] and block[new],just like that:

```
block[old], block[new] = block[new], block[old]
```

Comment: ohhhh thank you for the advice! But do you know how to solve my problem?? I'don't know why, but the exchange is not working :s

Comment: what is wrong is that block[new]= block[old], this sentence put block[old] to block[new], but the block[old] is no more the orgin one, the block[old] has put into aux, so, you should write block[new] = aux. understand?